# ActionController::UrlGenerationError No Routes Matches for Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with list of followings for a user where each following has a corresponding check box. The selected followings would be deleted on click of a button.

followings is a nested resource under users, i have a destroy method in my controller and when i do rake routes, i can see the route corresponding to followings#destroy action but when the followings list page is loaded it throws no routes matches error.

routes.rb:

```
    resources :users do
     resources :followings
     resources :events
    end
```

following_controller.rb:

```
    class FollowingsController < ApplicationController

    def index  
     @followings = Following.findFollowings(params.has_key?("user_id") ? params[:user_id] : current_user.id)
     @following = Following.new
    end

   def destroy
     Following.any_in(:following_id => params[:id]).destroy_all
     render index
   end

   end
```

index.html.haml:

```
    = form_for(@following, url: {action: 'destroy'}, :html => {:method => :delete, :role => 'form'}) do |f|
      - @followings.each do |following|
      = f.check_box "following_id"
      = f.submit  "Delete"
```

rake routes:

```
    user_followings GET    /users/:user_id/followings(.:format)          followings#index
                     POST   /users/:user_id/followings(.:format)          followings#create
  new_user_following GET    /users/:user_id/followings/new(.:format)      followings#new
 edit_user_following GET    /users/:user_id/followings/:id/edit(.:format) followings#edit
      user_following GET    /users/:user_id/followings/:id(.:format)      followings#show
                     PATCH  /users/:user_id/followings/:id(.:format)      followings#update
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/followings/:id(.:format)      followings#update
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/followings/:id(.:format)      followings#destroy
```

Error stack:

No route matches `{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"followings", :user_id=>"540f5c6b7072610a4c040000"}`
Extracted source (around line #9):

```
6  %ul
7      = render partial: "shared/npo_menu", locals: {item: 'followings'}
8  %section.following.notifications
9      = form_for(@following, url: {action: 'destroy'}, :html => {:method => :delete, :role => 'form'}) do |f|
10       .container
11          .row.manipulate
12              .pull-left
```

Thanks !

Comment: Looks like your indentation may be off, if the code is the same as what you pasted.  Should be an indent and then following.check_box?

Comment: The form layout looks a little unusual.  

Can you explain why you are using two different instance variables, "@following" and "@followings" for this view?  Also, why are you rendering a form in an index view (not saying it's wrong, but generally not what an index is used for).

Comment: @Kevin the indentation is correct in the actual code, just pasted few lines here and not the entire haml. "@followings" is the list which is to be displayed on the index page. "@following" is the for the list item when user selects them to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The routing problem is solved. For multiple deletes the route had to declared as collection. here are the changes which worked -

routes.rb

```
    resources :users do
      resources :followings do
        collection do
         delete 'destroy_multiple'
        end    
      end
      resources :events
   end
```

followings_controller.rb

```
    def destroy_multiple
      Following.any_in(:following_id => params[:id]).destroy_all

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_followings_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
   end
```

index.haml.html

```
    = form_tag destroy_multiple_user_followings_path, method: :delete do
```